# Label prediction to probability score prediction/AUC using scikit-learn SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm, auc

For a DS competition I was using SVM to do binary classification. Here tdata,vdata both have 256 features. tlabels,vlabels both have dimensions n_samples x 1 and their unique values are 0/1.

Now, as per the competition rules, in place of labels, we need to submit probability score(between 0 to 1) and AUC will be used to decide the ranking.

I am pretty new to SVMs and Sklearn. Any pointers on how to convert this code to generate probability scores and AUC, will be of great help.

Code:

```
classifier=svm.SVC(gamma=g,C=c,kernel='rbf',class_weight='balanced') 
classifier.fit(tdata, tlabels)
expected = vlabels
predicted = classifier.predict(vdata)

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted)
accuracy = (cm[0,0]+cm[1,1])*100.0/sum(sum(cm))
print("accuracy = "+str(accuracy))
```

Output:

```
Classification report for classifier SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight='balanced', coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma=0.00020000000000000001,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False):
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.93      0.88      0.90      1881
        1.0       0.92      0.95      0.94      2686

avg / total       0.92      0.92      0.92      4567


accuracy = 92.3144296037
```

Comment: Have you looked at [sklearn.metrics.auc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html)

Comment: Yes, but how do I modify the classifier to output probability scores between 0 and 1?

Comment: For the probabilities I posted an answer, for the AUC sklearn.metrics.auc should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Use `predict_proba` function of `SVC` for obtaining probabilities instead of classes.
To use `predict_proba` function on `SVC` parameter `probability=True` should be given while initalization.

```
classifier=svm.SVC(gamma=g,C=c,kernel='rbf',class_weight='balanced', probability=True) # parameter probability=True should be given
classifier.fit(tdata, tlabels)
expected = vlabels
predicted = classifier.predict(vdata)
pred_proba = classifier.predict_proba(vdata) # predict_proba function call

fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(labels, proba_one)
metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```

Reference:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

Comment: Does anyone know how can I convert predicted probabilities into class labels? My classification is not binary. I have taken average of two models and I need to convert them back to labels.

Comment: `predict_proba` gives a probability for each class label for every record. Suppose you have 4 class label this means for every record you'll have 4 probability (adding up to 1.0). You select the class label with the highest probability.

Comment: `predict_proba` is returning a one dimensional array, one probability value for each record. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486385/scikit-learn-convert-prediciton-probabilities-to-labelled-predictions) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Define: `probability=True in SVC` (this parameter is available for SVC) see [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

```
classifier=svm.SVC(gamma=g,C=c,kernel='rbf',class_weight='balanced', probability=True)
```

**Step 2**

Then you need to use `predict_proba` method.

Example:

```
classifier.fit(X,y)
classifier.predict_proba(X)
```

The result is the probabilities that you want in range [0,1].

Hope this helps.

[SVC link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

[predict_proba](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.libsvm.predict_proba.html)